# How to break the row into parts to fit the screen size

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to display a row from MySQL table based on the user input.

Since the table has many columns, I retrieve a lot of columns, for which the user has to scroll right to see all the data.

I am using the following code to display the content to the page.

```
$sql2="select * from student_information where student_id='$id'";
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

if($result2->num_rows > 0){
    echo '<table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="db-table">';
    echo '<tr><th>STUDENT__FIRST_NAME</th><th>STUDENT__LAST_NAME</th><th>STUDENT_ID</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>CITY</th><th>STATE</th><th>ZIP</th><th>COUNTRY</th><th>PHONE</th><th>DEPARTMENT</th><th>MAJOR</th>
<th>EMAIL</th><th>MAILING_ADDRESS</th><th>HEALTH_INSURANCE</th><th>CREDIT_HOURS</th><th>GROUP</th><th>GENDER</th><th>DOB</th><th>STATUS</th><th>NOTES</th><th>JOINED_ON</th></tr>';

    while($rowz2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($rowz2 as $key=>$value){
            echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo "</table><br/>";
}
else {
   echo "<h2>No data based on the entered values</h2>";
}
```

How can I break out of the output row and into two rows, so that the output row will be displayed in two parts, so that it fits the screen, without the need to scroll right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume the user screen has any defined width. it can range from a cell phone to an ultra wide monitor... better your table stays one record per line.

You can use some css responsive table tricks though

Check this out https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.